# Route 53 configuration for GoDaddy domain

Tags: godaddy, dns-servers, route53

I had purchased the domain on goDaddy a while back and now I am trying to setup an S3 static website.

I followed the instructions on setting the website from AWS manual

I followed the instructions on setting my route 53 migration from AWS manual

My Mail Exchange was having an issue after the switchover. So I used the default servers from GoDaddy on the route 53 record sets and that seems to be working.

but my site has not propagated yet and it still shows blank page.

**EDIT:** I am not getting any errors. It's just a blank page with

`<!DOCTYPE html><body style="padding:0; margin:0;"><html><body><iframe src="http://mcc.godaddy.com/park/ZGt0YwR2BP4lZwRhZmLh" style="visibility: visible;height: 100%; position:absolute" allowtransparency="true" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe></body></html>`

Also, it has been close to a week now since I have changed the settings

**EDIT2**: `http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com` works for me. So the issue is with the DNS and that's what I can't figure out.

Comment: Are you receiving a server error (e.g., 5XX), or a timeout while connecting? I'd suggest running a traceroute to see where you're ending up at. Try using some of the online tools [here](http://network-tools.com/). Also, it's helpful to know how long it's been. Normally if your MX is already resolving, your web server should be as well (so I'm suspecting there's a server configuration error at play).

Comment: Is the IP address reported that of your S3 bucket?   Are the name servers (NS records) pointing to amazon servers?     Also if you add an entry in your `/etc/hosts` (or `hosts.txt` file on Win) like `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx example.com www.example.com` using your domain name and your S3 bucket IP, does the website then work on that computer?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I am sorry for my ignorance but I am very new at this. As far as my understanding of the S3 user manuals suggest, the S3 buckets don't have static IPs. The IP in the `A` record shows on the dig report. the Name Servers from the route53 also show up on that

Comment: From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html It looks like you should be able to access your content at `http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com`.   If that doesn't work, it isn't a DNS problem.  If that does work, you need to fix DNS.

Comment: Can you post your actual domain name?   Also add screenshots of how you configured your NS records at the registry and how you set up records in Route 53.

Comment: 184.168.221.36 is GoDaddy's domain parking server.   You are using Route 53 to point to the wrong thing. gabehou is correct in his answer, you need to use alias records to point to bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com.  (Since you have email set up, a CNAME record at the apex would break mail, so use ALIAS records instead.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for sticking with me through this. @StephenOstermiller appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DNS records are not configured correctly. There are A records that are still pointing to a different location while the CNAME is pointing to your Bucket.  Remove you CNAME that is pointing to the buckets and edit the A records make sure to set yes to ALIAS and remove the wildcard A record the one with the *

You should only have 2 A records and both should be set yes to  **ALIAS**

www.example.com A ALIAS s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

example.com A ALIAS s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com